# How can I resolve the error bash: example.com.chained.crt: Permission denied

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

In trying to install an ssl certificate on ubuntu running nginx, when I run sudo cat example.com.crt intermediate.crt > example.com.chained.crt I get the error

bash: example.com.chained.crt: Permission denied

example.com depicts the actual domain name for the ssl certificate which for policy reason's I am not allowed to post on a public forum

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue after running chmod on the /etc/nginx/ssl directory

then I had to change to the ssl directory and then run the command sudo cat example.com.crt intermediate.crt > example.com.chained.crt, see URL below which I followed in trying to install ssl certificate from godaddy on nginx

https://marcosantonocito.medium.com/steps-to-install-a-go-daddy-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04-ff942b9fd7ff